# Python GNP package error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 4894: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, parsing, encoding

I'm trying to download the Google News Feed parser package in python and encountered the following error:

```
Collecting gnp
  Using cached gnp-0.0.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\ajlow\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\gnp\setup.py", line 6, in <module>
        long_description = file.read()
      File "C:\Users\ajlow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 4894: character maps to <undefined>
```

How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when using a standard script to download and install a package. There is not much you can do other than report the problem to the package maintainer(s).